# How do I make PlaySound load only some parts of the song C++

Tags: c++, ram, playsound

I have a 424 mb wav file, which I want to play, but it takes a lot of time to load, and it uses 425.6 mb of ram. Way too much ram for a dos format program. I want to load only a part of the song, then when it's almost at the final, load the second part, when the second part is played, remove from ram the first part, and etc. For this I should use 50 parts.
Here is the line of code:
`PlaySound("../music/main.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC);`
I mention that I need to run this in background, while the other commands do their roles.

Comment: You have listed the function signature for something designed to run on the MS Windows platform, yet are talking about DOS. These are seemingly contradictions. Are you talking about actual pre-windows DOS, or a command-prompt window from inside MS Windows? (PlaySound is not available under DOS)

Comment: @enhzflep I suspect by DOS format program they mean Win32 console application. That's the only context in which using PlaySound makes sense.

Comment: You can't do that. Someone might be able to help you figure out some other method if you explained what a "dos format program" is.

Comment: @ComicSansMS - Me too, for the same reason you mention. Part of my reasoning in asking the question was to probe the possibility that this is an XY problem. Nothing running windows in any meaningful sense has a problem coming up with 500 meg of ram these days. It'd be a shame to do a whole heap of memory preserving work without good reason. That said, it's not very hard to maintain a couple of buffers and then simply fill one with a couple spare to soak up disk latency. No audio artefacts is quite easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlaySound` is a fairly high-level function, so it's tricky to get behavior like this. In particular, you will likely experience small silent gaps between playing back the different parts. So the best solution would be to go to a lower-level API that allows more sophisticated managing of sound playback buffers. [OpenAL](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft) is a good library for doing this, the modern Windows native solution is [WASAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi), which unfortunately is quite complicated to use.

With `PlaySound` itself, first adjust your program to load the `.wav` file to memory and then use `SND_MEMORY` for playing it from memory ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162086/play-manipulated-volume-levels-in-playsound-with-snd-memory)).

Now, instead of loading the whole `.wav` file at once, you just load the header and as many soundframes as fill your buffer. You then create your own `.wav` header for just those loaded samples and put it all in a contiguous buffer. You basically build your own, smaller `.wav` file in memory. Then you call `PlaySound(..., SND_MEMORY)` on that buffer. Rinse and repeat for the remaining samples from the original file.

Note that you will need your own `.wav` file format parser for this, but the file format is not that complicated, so hopefully this should not be too much of an issue.